# Determine ntile of grouped variable compared to overall dataframe

Tags: r

I have a large dataset of grouped observations, I am trying to do get a quartile or other ntile of where each group compares to the rest of the observations.

I have tried ntile of cumsum and similar methods, but I r gets extremely angry with outputs errors or I get quartile of 1 for every observation.  I have also tried comparing the ntile to the parent dataframe, r didn't like that either.

I am sure this is super simple but my brain is fried today.

```
df <- tibble(ID= c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"),
           population = c(10, 200, 3000, 40000, 120, 220, 3300, 44000))
df <- group_by(df, ID) %>% 
  summarize(quartile = ntile(2, 4))
```

I expect to have a 1-4 quartile as it splits based on the different sizes of the population.

Instead, everything simply shows as 1 and I cannot figure out why.

What I am hoping for:

```
ID quartile
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4
```

EDIT:

```
df <- mutate(df, 
             quartile = ntile(x = population, 4))
```

gives me the correct output... however it doesn't work as intended when used on my data frame

Comment: since you groupby , there is only one value in each group ,so you will only have 1 as out put

Comment: Any ideas on how to get to my goal?

Comment: I have add a answer about it

Comment: I've been getting this problem as well. Every quantile is 1

Answer (score 0):

Seems no need `group_by` here

```
df['quartile']=ntile(df$population,4)
df
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID population quartile
  <chr>      <dbl>    <int>
1     a         10        1
2     b        200        2
3     c       3000        3
4     d      40000        4
```

Comment: You are right in this df but my actual data does need to be grouped, I think you might be right about getting out of the summarize, but I do need to group